# Ubuntu re-mounts the root partition during normal startup

Tags: 16.04, mount, ext4, initramfs

I noticed that Ubuntu re-mounts my EXT4 root partition during normal startup:

```
$ dmesg | grep -i ext4
[    9.460928] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)

[    9.864392] EXT4-fs (sda1): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
```

The 'errors=remount-ro' is simply the mount option from my fstab. If replace them with 'defaults' I get:

```
$ dmesg | grep -i ext4
[    8.318300] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    8.706887] EXT4-fs (sda1): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
```

What could be the explanation of this?

My personal theory is that it is initramfs that does the first mount and the second is for my normal OS. Can anybody confirm or reject this theory?

*Bonus: the system works fine and I see this on my other Ubuntu machines aswell.*

Comment: You could have put in your question then that the partition is mounting properly and working OK.  That to me is just a message during boot up.  If you boot the system to recovery mode it is always in Read Only by default until you remount it as Read / Write which bypasses fstab.

Comment: @Terrance Ok, noted.